# P-values for quantile regression with replicate weight via the 'survey' withReplicates function

Tags: regression, survey

I have been able to successfully apply BRR estimated weights to `rq()` using the `survey` and `quantreg` packages in R.

The model comes out fine, I am able to obtain the $\theta$ and SEs, but I also want the $p$-values. Unlike with `rq()` where one is able get the $t$ and $p$-value etc, this approach does not provided the $p$-values but only the $\theta$ and SE.

R script:

```
mod<-withReplicates(repwtx,quote(coef
                   (rq(logA~ dose+ chtcm + cage +raceth + sex,
                       tau=0.9, weights=.weights,alpha=0.05))))
```

and here's the output I get

```
>mod
                 theta     SE
(Intercept)  1.3314065 0.1809
dose         0.3255046 0.0367
chtcm        0.0322069 0.0100
cage        -0.0516363 0.0154
raceth      -0.0082423 0.0196
sex          0.2314573 0.2887
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure that the r survey package will print the p-value directly, but assuming there aren't any weird normality assumptions with your data, you can get the confidence interval with..

```
confint( mod )
```

..and from there, you can either calculate the p-value from that by following the steps in [this article](http://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d2304) or you can get a rough idea of what it is by running commands like..

```
confint( mod , level = 0.95 )
confint( mod , level = 0.99 )
confint( mod , level = 0.999 )
```

..and observing when the intervals cross zero.  ;)